# Running an executable jar of SWT/JFace project on the other Computers

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, swt, executable

I am creating a SWT/JFace project and exporting as executable jar.  But this jar is not working on the other computers. When use double clicks the jar nothing happens. I am sure that other user has JRE installed.

I think problem is the Referanced Libraries. Beause near the libraries its written 
 C:\Users\Turgut - İhracat.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.12.50.v20170928-1321.jar

Here is the Screen capture of libraries. Any helps will be apriciated..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Remove all referenced jars,
- Create a 'lib' folder in your project,
- Paste your referenced jars into
  'lib' folder;
- Add these jars into 'classpath'

***If this not work, execute your jar via command line to see the error.***